# MongoDB Aggregation $in and return document in result even it does not exist

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

A query with an `$in` operator. If one of the values in the `$in` does not exist, I would still like to return a result for it.

For instance:

```
$match: {
      serviceIdRef: {
        $in: [
          "1",
          "2",
          "3"
        ]
      }
```

There are no `serviceIdRef=3` in the collection. But I would still like to return a document in the result. For example:

```
{ 
    "_id=1",
    ..... // rest of data for _id=1
},
{ 
    "_id=2",
    ..... // rest of data for _id=2
},
{
    "_id": "3" // there is no entry in the collection but we still return this from the $in clause
}
```

Please see the [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/f1sdaiO5bRS). Is that possible?

Comment: I'm confused. how do you expect us to return something for serviceIdRef=3 when it doesn't exist? you can't return something that doesn't exist....

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight way to return not exists document in result, you have to do it after query in your client-side language, I am not sure what language you are using, but i have added in JS, and there are many logics in JS.

```js
let queryIds = ["1", "2", "3"];
let result = [
  {
    "_id": "2",
    "serviceName": "my-service-2",
    "state": [
      {
        "count": 1,
        "pubState": "ACTIVE",
        "sample": [
          {
            "_id": "245",
            "pubName": "p1",
            "pubState": "ACTIVE",
            "serviceIdRef": "2",
            "serviceName": "my-service-2",
            "subName": "c1"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "serviceName": "my-service-1",
    "state": [
      {
        "count": 2,
        "pubState": "INVITED",
        "sample": [
          {
            "_id": "244",
            "pubName": "p1",
            "pubState": "INVITED",
            "serviceIdRef": "1",
            "serviceName": "my-service-1",
            "subName": "c1"
          },
          {
            "_id": "242",
            "pubName": "p1",
            "pubState": "INVITED",
            "serviceIdRef": "1",
            "serviceName": "my-service-1",
            "subName": "c1"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

const mergeArrays = (arr1 = [], arr2 = []) => {
   let res = [];
   res = arr1.map(_id => {
      const index = arr2.findIndex(el => el["_id"] == _id);
      const r = index !== -1 ? arr2[index] : {};
      return Object.assign({ _id }, r);
   });
   return res;
};

console.log(mergeArrays(queryIds, result));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select something that doesn't exists by injecting documents in the pipeline.

On the first 3 stages of the pipeline you prepare the empty set, add and array of IDs you are after, and unwind them to create a template collection with 1 empty document per ID.

On the next stage you merge it with the actual collection using $lookup to itself. The key here is to use "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays" unwinding the matches, which will let you have empty documents.

The final 2 stages are just re-shaping documents to the original form.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "serviceIdRef": [
        "1",
        "2",
        "3"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$serviceIdRef"
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "collection",
      "localField": "serviceIdRef",
      "foreignField": "serviceIdRef",
      "as": "doc"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": {
      path: "$doc",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: 0,
      serviceIdRef: 1,
      doc: {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          {
            serviceIdRef: "$serviceIdRef",
            _id: null
          },
          "$doc"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$doc"
    }
  }
])
```

I didn't quite understand what you tried to do with in the playground pipeline, but I guess you can take it from here.

The documents without matching serviceIdRef will look like

```
{
  "_id": null,
  "serviceIdRef": "3"
}
```

So bear in mind the _id may not be unique as you may have more than 1 missing document.